# Javascript - delete specific elements out of a collection?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-7

(**NOTE:**  I'm trying to get this working in Internet Explorer 7, but this also has to work with Chrome and Firefox, as well as later versions of IE.)

I have an HTML Form element that I need to walk through and delete some fields from before submitting the form.  Basically, I need to remove any field of tag="BUTTON" because otherwise it will screw up the server-side processing.

Is there an easy way to do that?   I'm thinking of something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<formObject.length;i++) {
    if (formObject[i].tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        formObject.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work, I got **"Object Doesn't Support This Property Or Method."**

So instead of `splice()`  I tried `formObject.removeChild(formObject[i])`, which gave me **"Invalid Argument."**

If I simply try `formObject.removeChild(i)` I get **"Type Mismatch."**

How can I remove these elements?

**More Information:**   In Chrome, when using `removeChild()` I get the error messasge "The node to be removed is not a child of this node."   So apparently the node has to be a DIRECT child.   But I still can't figure out how to grab this node and remove it from this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
var formObject = document.forms[formName];
for (i=0;i<formObject.length;i++) {
    if (formObject[i].tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        formObject[i].parentNode.removeChild(formObject[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```